# pd.read_csv causes pyplot fail to render

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm new to Python.

For some reason when imported data from any .csv file,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataFrame = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')

plt.hist([2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

csv1.csv (actually any legit csv will be good here)

```
"Group A","Group B"
3,2
4,1
0,1
```

pyplot fail to render:

```
(...)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 2120, in tick_values
    vmin, vmax = mtransforms.nonsingular(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 2880, in nonsingular
    if maxabsvalue < (1e6 / tiny) * np.finfo(float).tiny:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/getlimits.py", line 462, in __new__
    dtype = numeric.dtype(type(dtype))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

[screenshot of the empty figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzhUo.png)

But, removing the

```
dataFrame = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')
```

and everything is good to go.
plt.scatter() also fails to render, not just hist().

I do not to understand why pyplot behaves that way.

Are pandas and matplotlib somehow not compatible?

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, do check that your file is not currepted. If not try to give encoding argument like this `pd.read('file_name.csv', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Can I have the link to that function please. I am not seeing it anywhere on pandas newest documents.

Comment: I meant `pd.read_csv` not `pd.read`, make sure to do `import pandas as pd` [check here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: `encoding` has no effect. Seems like I will have to work on Windows for a while then.

Comment: Are you able to see csv file in ms excel?

Comment: I used VS Code to view/edit the .csv, it looks fine. The error only shows on macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Python are you using? There's an issue with python 3.10, pd.read_csv(), and numeric.dtype, documented here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41935

Comment: I downgraded to 3.8.10 & it's working fine now. Thanks for pointing that out.